# Problems DVD playback in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dvd, dvd-audio

I have followed:

Ubuntu 10.04 (i386, amd64), 10.10, 11.04, 11.10, 12.04, and 12.10 (i386, amd64)
Works for old releases that are no longer supported if you have repositories on CD/DBD or somewhere. So anything from 9.04 onwards. The last LTS, 10.04, worked this way. The current LTS, 12.04 and the recent 12.10 also work this way.

Install the libdvdread4 package (no need to add third party repositories) via Synaptic or command line: (note: if you have installed *ubuntu-restricted-extras this has already been installed automatically for you)

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
Then open a terminal window and execute:

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
Rebooting may be necessary.
After this, VLC will automatically use it. Some programs may need recompilation."
```

The DVD plays but then starts to lag the freezes so I have looked at various DMA  forums but have had no joy.

One forum stated providing the following readings below:

```
sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda

Timing cached reads:   1648 MB in  2.00 seconds = 823.64 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 330 MB in  3.01 seconds = 109.79 MB/sec

desktop:~$ sudo dmesg |grep DMA
[    0.000000]   DMA      0x00000010 -> 0x00001000
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 32 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 3951 pages, LIFO batch:0
[    0.697396] ata1: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xffa0 irq 14
[    0.697399] ata2: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xffa8 irq 15
[    0.698873] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xd080 ctl 0xd000 bmdma 0xc800 irq 19
[    0.698876] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xcc00 ctl 0xc880 bmdma 0xc808 irq 19
[    0.876354] ata1.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-4163B, A102, max UDMA/33
[    0.876538] ata3.00: ATA-8: ST3500418AS, CC38, max UDMA/133
[    0.892236] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
[    0.892422] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    7.557326] parport0: PC-style at 0x378 (0x778), irq 7, dma 3 [PCSPP,TRISTATE,COMPAT,ECP,DMA]
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!